# When to use pointers when defining structs

Tags: pointers, go

Ive noticed in some libraries that when they define structs some values have pointers while others don't. I can't seem to find anywhere explaining when to use pointers and when not to.

Example

```
type MyStruct struct {
     FieldOne     *int64 
     FieldTwo     int64
     FieldFour    *AnotherStruct
     FieldFive    AnotherStruct
}
```

What are the benefits of using a pointer ?

Comment: Pointers are useful when you want to differentiate between a "zero" value and a non-value, i.e. `nil`.

Comment: Let me share this article. I think it has some good information on when you might or might not want to use pointers: https://medium.com/@meeusdylan/when-to-use-pointers-in-go-44c15fe04eac . There are more articles out there on this same topic if you find yourself wanting to hear more opinions, but I think this one covers most common points.

Comment: to prevent memory duplication when performing changes of a shared state.

Comment: @mh-bon that's a reason to use a pointer to the outer struct, not a reason to use pointer fields.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I will try to not use pointer value in a struct because it may be root cause of panic, if we forgot to check nil before use it. Have three reason when I use a pointer value in a struct:

1. This field is a big struct so I think it can help to reduce copy costs (It's correct in C/C++, but in go, some case the Benchmark test showed same result).
2. When I need to check and do some thing if this value is nil (Because of default values in go and the cost to compare with AnotherStruct{}).
3. When i need "omitempty" (ignore this field if it empty) to convert fields of struct to bson or json ...
   I hope 2) and 3) can help to answers for your question. If you have any better idea please share me. Because I also new on go!

Comment: #1 only makes sense if the field is a large struct or array type. Otherwise, the pointer is already likely 8 bytes and isn't going to be appreciably faster than copying a value.